# Java Class Inheritance and comparing subclass objects

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm working on a homework assignment, and I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around how to compare two of the same subclass objects.
Basically I have this superclass Magnitude:

```
class Magnitude {
    public boolean lessThan(Magnitude m) {

    }
    public boolean lessThanEqualTo(Magnitude m) {

    }
    public boolean equalTo(Magnitude m) {

    }
    public boolean greaterThan(Magnitude m) {

    }
    public boolean notEqual(Magnitude m) {

    }
}
```

And then I have a subclass Currency that extends Magnitude ( I am only allowed to override the lessThan() method):

```
class Currency extends Magnitude {
   double amount;

   public Currency(double amt) {
       this.amount = amt;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean lessThan(Magnitude m) {
      Currency other_currency = (Currency) m;

      if (this.amount < other_currency.amount) {
          return true;
      }
      else {
         return false
      }
   }

   public void print() {
       System.out.println(amount);
   }
}
```

What exactly is the way that I should implement these methods for the super and subclass so that I can compare 2 objects of the same subclass?

Comment: You can use equalTo(Currency) method to compare to objects.

Comment: [`Object.equals(Object obj);`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/object_equals.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that you can call `lessThan()` also from `m` and use `this` as the other argument.

```
abstract class Magnitude {
public abstract boolean lessThan(Magnitude m);

public boolean lessThanEqualTo(Magnitude m) {
     return this.lessThan(m) || this.equalTo(m);
}
public boolean equalTo(Magnitude m) {
     return ((!this.lessThan(m))&&(!m.lessThan(this)));
}
public boolean greaterThan(Magnitude m) {
    return m.lessThen(this);
}
public boolean notEqual(Magnitude m) {
    return !this.equal(m);
}
```

}

You then need to have

```
class Currency extends Magnitude {
double amount;

public Currency(double amt) {
    this.amount = amt;
}

@Override
public boolean lessThan(Magnitude m) {
  Currency other_currency = (Currency) m;

  if (this.amount < other_currency.amount) {
      return true;
  }
  else {
     return false
  }
}

public void print() {
   System.out.println(amount);
}
}
```

Comment: How do I make lessThan abstract?? I'm getting an error when I try to do so.

Comment: You could simplify this by making the implementation of `notEqual` `this.lessThan(m) || m.lessThan(this)`, and simply making `equalTo` `!notEqual(m)`.

Comment: @JornVernee It is an example of how to implement it. I agree you can write it in many possible ways, but I would not call them to simplify

Comment: @RaduIonescu when I make the changes to making Magnitude abstract I get this error: <identifier> expected

Comment: never mind I figured it out, it needs to be abstract class Magnitude {}

Answer (score 0):

Simply rewrite the methods at the subclass.

Now, if you create two instances of the subclass and compare them, it'll use the subclass method

`Currency c1 = new Currency();
 Currency c2 = new Currency();
 c1.lessThan(c2); //will call Currency.lessThan method`

To use parent's class method, use this way
`c1.lessThan((Magnitude) c2);`

See [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html) form more info.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to implement and override the `lessThan()` method in your `Currency` class, knowing you can only compare currencies but not magnitudes, but what you receive is a `Magnitude` type parameter.

In that case, you need to check if the `Magnitude` object you received as a paramether is actually an instance of `Currency` wrapped in a `Magnitude` class. To do that, you use the [instanceof comparison operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) and then cast the object to `Currency`:

```
@Override
 public boolean lessThan(Magnitude m) {
    if(m instanceof Currency) {
        return this.amount < ((Currency)m).amount;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter is not a Currency");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I figured out how to implement and override the lessThan() method, I'm just trying to figure out how to implement the other methods in the superclass such as notEqual()

Comment: Well, a `Magnitude` type sounds a little abstract logically, so you need to think how two `Magnitude` objects should be compared in your solution and then write it as code. If they cannot be compared, then you should make it an interface or an abstract class.